# Entity Framework, update model from database, no 'Table' arrow

Tags: entity-framework-4, edmx, edmx-designer

I have an edmx that resides in VS2012...when changing the App.config to have the edmx point to a database on my local machine, I cannot access any tables to add using the right-click 'Update Model from Database...' option.

The dialog comes up, and normally there is an expander arrow to the left of Tables, which when clicked expands Tables and shows the schemas, and I can choose tables to add.

But after changing the App.config, the expander arrow to the left of Tables no longer displays, and I cannot add tables to the model.

What would preclude the expander arrow from showing?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions? Try connecting through SSMS to your local DB using all the connection details specified in your app.config file and verify that user has permission to see the tables.

Comment: That's exactly what it was...had to put the App.config user in the db_owner role.  Thanks for the quick response.